# Gif animation on JellyBean 4.2 doesn't display

Tags: android, movie

I'm using

- Nexus 7 android 4.2
- SDK and eclipse is the adt-bundle-windows version. *download on 2012-11-21st
- OS is Windows7 64bits home premium sp1

I tried to run the sample code at

> ...\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics\BitmapDecode.java.

It is successfully build and run on both simulator and my nexus 7. The problem is the app doesn't display the `*.gif` animation but the the other 3 `*.bmp` is shown correctly. There even doesn't has any black box on the screen.

I tried different `*.gif` file which from internet or `SDK` example image file.

And I have attached the files at google group. [Here is the link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2IA8MjOjO_4).

In debug mode, I checked some parameter and as below:

1. the inputstream having the same length with the gif file, so I think is read successfully.
2. The Movie.draw x,y is having a positive number.
3. May be the frame rate is too high, so I tried to slow down by putting a delay and tried Movie.setTime(10); So it atleast must show some static picture. But at my device/simulator just got blank screen.

Thank you.

Regards,
Murnesty

Answer (score -1):

Android doesn't support animated GIFs.

Comment: Then how come there is a sample project with gif file. It's wasting my time and I overcome it by using animatied-list.